# How to connect UCMA 4.0/5.0 client to LYNC server

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, ucma

I am creating an UCMA client application with `UserEndpoint`. When connected to our organization's Lync server inside internal domain, my UCMA application is able to establish connection with server.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration;

namespace SimpleUserUCMA
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string sipaddress = "sip:example@domain.com";
        private const string username = "example@domain.com";
        private const string password = "password@1234";
        private const string domain = "domain.com";
        private const string destinationSip = "liveagent1@ngwplab.com";//serveraddress@domain.com
        private const string IMMessage = "Hello";


        static CollaborationPlatform _collabPlatform { get; set; }
        static UserEndpoint _endpoint { get; set; }
        static bool _OKToQuit = false;
        private static InstantMessagingCall call;
        private static InstantMessagingFlow flow;
        private static string incomingMessage;
        private static ManualResetEvent incomingMessageWaiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent flowWaiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36";

            var platformSettings = new ClientPlatformSettings(userAgent, Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.SipTransportType.Tls);
            _collabPlatform = new CollaborationPlatform(platformSettings);

            //Start up the platform, calling back asynchronously once it's done.
            _collabPlatform.BeginStartup(EndCollabPlatformStartup, null);

            // Wait for a message to arrive and the flow to be ready.
            incomingMessageWaiter.WaitOne();
            flowWaiter.WaitOne();

            // Process the incoming message. For this example just echo what was received.
            var reply = "You send me: " + incomingMessage;

            // And reply to the sender.
            SendReplyMessage(reply);
            //In this example, wait for everything to finish before exiting
            while (!_OKToQuit)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        private static void EndCollabPlatformStartup(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            _collabPlatform.EndStartup(ar);
            //A collaboration plaform can have one or more Endpoints. An Endpoint is tied to a SIP Address.            
            UserEndpointSettings settings = new UserEndpointSettings(sipaddress,"00.000.63.216",5061);
            settings.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
            settings.AutomaticPresencePublicationEnabled = true;

            _endpoint = new UserEndpoint(_collabPlatform, settings);
            _endpoint.BeginEstablish(UserEndpointEstablishCompleted, _endpoint);

        }


        private static void UserEndpointEstablishCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

            try
            {
                var currentEndpoint = ar.AsyncState as LocalEndpoint;
                <strong>currentEndpoint.EndEstablish(ar);</strong>

                //Once the endpoint is in place, wait for a conversation to arrive.
                _endpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<InstantMessagingCall>(HandleInstantMessagingCall);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex);
            }


        }

        private static void HandleInstantMessagingCall(object sender, CallReceivedEventArgs<InstantMessagingCall> e)
        {
            if (e.ToastMessage != null && e.ToastMessage.HasTextMessage)
            {
                // Store the incoming message text.
                incomingMessage = e.ToastMessage.Message;
                // Signal that we have a message.
                incomingMessageWaiter.Set();
            }

            call = e.Call;
            call.InstantMessagingFlowConfigurationRequested += HandleInstantMessagingFlowConfigurationRequested;
            call.BeginAccept(EndCallAccept, null);
        }

        private static void EndCallAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            call.EndAccept(ar);
        }

        private static void HandleInstantMessagingFlowConfigurationRequested(object sender, InstantMessagingFlowConfigurationRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            flow = e.Flow;
            flow.MessageReceived += HandleFlowMessageReceived;
            flow.StateChanged += HandleFlowStateChanged;
        }

        private static void HandleFlowMessageReceived(object sender, InstantMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.HasTextBody)
            {
                // Store the incoming message text.
                incomingMessage = e.TextBody;
                // Signal that we have a message.
                incomingMessageWaiter.Set();
            }

        }


        static void HandleFlowStateChanged(object sender, MediaFlowStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.State == MediaFlowState.Active)
            {
                // Signal that the flow is ready.
                flowWaiter.Set();
            }
        }

        private static void SendReplyMessage(string reply)
        {
            // Send the message to the requestor.
            flow.BeginSendInstantMessage(reply, EndBeginSendInstanceMessage, null);
        }

        private static void EndBeginSendInstanceMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            flow.EndSendInstantMessage(ar);

            // Having sent the message, terminate the conversation
            flow.Call.Conversation.BeginTerminate(EndBeginTerminate, flow.Call.Conversation);
        }

        private static void EndBeginTerminate(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Conversation conversation = (Conversation)ar.AsyncState;
            conversation.EndTerminate(ar);

            _OKToQuit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error when I try to establish end user connection using UCMA 5.0

When I debug it breaks at this line :

```cs
var currentEndpoint = ar.AsyncState as LocalEndpoint;
currentEndpoint.EndEstablish(ar);
```

Error:

```
ERROR : ErrorCode=-2146893022
FailureReason=IncorrectNameInRemoteCertificate
LocalEndpoint=100.77.120.70:53578
RemoteEndpoint=52.176.63.216:5061
RemoteCertificate=<null>
Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.TlsFailureException:The target principal name is incorrect ---> Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.TLSException: outgoing TLS negotiation failed; Wrong target principal name configured. HRESULT=-2146893022
   at Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.TlsTransportHelper.HandleNegotiationFailure(Int32 status, Boolean incoming)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.TlsTransportHelper.OutgoingTlsNegotiation(TransportsDataBuffer receivedData, TransportsDataBuffer& pDataToSend)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.TlsTransportHelper.NegotiateConnection(TransportsDataBuffer receivedData, TransportsDataBuffer& pDataToSend)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.TlsTransport.DelegateNegotiation(TransportsDataBuffer receivedData)
   at Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Sip.TlsTransport.OnReceived(Object data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

`UserEndpointSettings settings = new UserEndpointSettings(sipaddress,"00.000.63.216",5061);`

The servername can't be a IP address when you are connecting via TLS, it has to match the certificate name returned from the server.  So you need the servername of the FE pool that the user uri is homed to.

Why don't you use the non-server version of the constructor?

`UserEndpointSettings settings = new UserEndpointSettings(sipaddress);`

and let the UCMA sort out the server to connect to for you using Skypes autodiscovery process?

Comment: Initially i have only tried that but was getting an error " SupportedAuthenticationProtocols=Ntlm, Kerberos "

Comment: ErrorCode=-2146893039
Microsoft.Rtc.Signaling.AuthenticationException:Unable to perform authentication of credentials. That why , I passed the endpoints for the connection establishment

Comment: I think you are getting further as this is a layer above tls that is failing.  This is getting away from a programming question and more of a system admin question.  You need to try to track down why authentication is failing.  I would dump all the exception information to see what else it is saying.  If the machine you are running this on is not a member of the domain then it could be a certificate problem, or else you may need to hunt down why Kerberos is failing (most likely on the DC server).

Comment: I'm not much sure I can be any more help as this is getting way out of my area of understanding.